# VB.NET - AddressOf returns Nothing?

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, address-operator

Short question: can VB.NET operator AddressOf return Nothing in any case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, you always have to give the reference of a valid method in an AddressOf statement, or you'll have a compiler error.

Comment: That's what I thought but it was one of those moments when one need to hear something from someone else to make sure ;)